# What is the 'correct' approach to clean code UI in Delphi Pascal?

Tags: user-interface, delphi, coding-style

I'm quite new to Delphi Pascal, and i'm not sure if this Question suits SO, but i don't really know where to ask this else.

My issue is, that i try to develop a Delphi Pascal application, that has an UI (nothing too complex, but rather an input mask with many inputs, such as TEdit, TComboBox, etc., aswell as a TVirtualStringTree that is used to display data (none database data for that matter)). Since there are many UI elements, i want to seperate some of the elements into their own units, to avoid overloading a single unit with dozens of procedures and functions handling the UI logic. However, since Delphi Pascal doesn't allow circular references, this doesn't seem straight forward (because i would need access to the original form, which contained the seperated element). I tried working around this, by just passing the said elements as a member into their own respective types in the seperated unit, but when i do this, i always get access violation exceptions (Am i doing something wrong?).

So therefore my question is, how to approach UI code cleanly in delphi pascal?

Comment: Maybe frames would help.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on this?

Comment: Frames would be separate units with their own collections of components and methods, and you can display the frames (or not) as needed.

Comment: You mean to put all the relevant elements in a seperat frame, that is part of a different unit, and then add that frame back to the main frame? Can i access the components of the sub frame in the main frame then?

Comment: Although I personally dislike it, Delphi actually allows circular unit references when they are in the implementation section. F.i.: If A uses B in the interface section then B can use A in the implementation section.

Comment: @UweRaabe Yes but this means i can't store it in the type B

Comment: The "correct" way to handle this is to de-couple your data/logic from your UI.  Your data/logic code should have no knowledge of your UI code, and vice versa.  Use properties, callback/events, etc to pass around data from one to the other as needed. That will better isolate your code, make it easier to test and update, etc

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes. I'm aware of this. My question was more targetting the correct way to split up UI Elements to prevent units from becoming hard to read and maintain.

Comment: The main (or other) _form_ can contain _frames_ that are separate units, each with its own set of components and supporting code. Frames can be displayed or hidden as needed on a form. Just do a little research about frames to see if that is what you want.

Comment: As others have mentioned, you're looking to use `TFrame` descendants to hold the various sections of your form. https://www.google.com/search?q=delphi+tframe+tutorial

Comment: "Can i access the components of the sub frame in the main frame then?"  Yes, you can.  For example, in your form you can refer to Frame1.Edit1.Text.

Comment: "I tried working around this, by just passing the said elements as a member into their own respective types in the seperated unit, but when i do this, i always get access violation exceptions (Am i doing something wrong?)."  Probably, but we'd need to see an example of your code to determine what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment No need. Splitting up the UI into sub-frames, as suggested by Ron Maupin works just fine. However, thanks for confirming that passing UI-Elements **should** work. Could be useful in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Delphi does allow "circular references" to a point. In your main form you can add references to your other units in the interface `uses` clause. In the other units you reference the main form in the implementation `uses` clause. You could also do it the other way around. You just can't have references in the interface section for both units/forms.

I also don't think there is a huge problem with dozens of routines that handle the UI, existing in one unit. It comes down to striking a balance between one big file or lots of little files. Which is easier to maintain? Some Delphi source files have many thousands of lines (e.g. System.Classes.pas has more than 20,000 lines). Don't be afraid of big files.

Comment: Yes, but this means (like i mentioned in the comments of the post) that there can't be a member of type A (unit uA) in type B (unit uB), because i can't reference the unit uA in the declaration of type B before using unit uA (and vice versa). However, as mentioned, Ron Maupin's solution works just fine.

Sure, big files are normal, but i personally prefer to have a modular structure with units only containing it's relevant variables and procedures/functions in itself. Also, i think a lot of LOC's could be saved if Delphi had DataBindings (like e.g. WPF).

Comment: I'm not familiar with frames, I'll have to have a closer look at them. FWIW, when I can't get around having to have circular references in the interface section, I declare a variable as a basic TObject or Pointer in the interface section and then cast it to the actual object when I access it in the implementation section. It's not perfect but it works. Just another way to skin the cat :)